# Friendly URL architecture

Tags: php, friendly-url

There is a catalog of goods, you need to make a filter for it.
Please help me understand the construction of architecture.

The filter will contain, for example: section, subsection, country, brand, type of product.

`Example: https://example.com/wine/white/france/petrus/dry`

But the client wants to make it so that it would be possible to select several in a different order, while maintaining a friendly URL.
How will my script understand that 1 request is a country and not a brand, for example?

`Example: https://example.com/wine/white/petrus/dry`

or

`Example: https://example.com/wine/white/france/dry`

Are there any assumptions in the implementation?
Checking for matches is not an option. France can be for example both a country and a brand (maybe).

Comment: Do these filters have to be supplied in that specific order?

Comment: This is the problem, that the order can be any)

Comment: Why should such a requirement exist? Those "friendly" URLs are nothing that someone will type into the address bar of a browser. They are constructed by the catalog logic, I would expect, by some filter or search mechanism. That means that the logic can work based on an implicit order of aspects, so a fixed order. And to answer your question: no, there is no magical component somewhere that could _guess_ what is meant by a URL not following such a scheme.

Comment: You obviously could simply work without any meaning of filter aspects and make a catalog search based on brute force search. But that would be highly inefficient.

Comment: In principle, this was clear to me from the beginning, but my colleague insisted on the opposite, I will go and prove to him the opposite))
Thank)

Comment: This is not about "proving" something. There is no right or wrong. This is about what makes sense. And it is the task of a good consultant to advise a client instead of blindly trying to implement what is requested.

Comment: One suggestion, in case you really cannot get around that (I know that reality is a beasty thing sometimes)... What about naming the otherwise implicit order in a "friendly" way? So a URL scheme like `https://example.com/cstbu/france/wine/dry/petrus/white`, where the "cstbu"  codes the order of the filters, here country, section, type, brand, subsection?

Comment: Good idea, ty :)